# Python function for changing text size in Python Shell

Tags: python

I want a function for changing the text size by code, not from the shell settings, I've been looking for something but I didn't find anything, is there any simple modality, I want something similar to the text below

```
import sys
import time
def delay_print(s):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.10)
delay_print("I want this text big")
```

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is unfortunately not possible. There's no way* for Python to control the printed text size, that's simply 100% dependent on the settings of your terminal emulator.

The only way you could sort of do this, would be to use [ASCII graphics](https://www.google.com/search?q=ascii+art+letters&tbm=isch) to print the large letters.

<sup>* You also could change your terminal's settings programmatically, but that would change the font of your whole console and not just one line. And that's anyways too broad to be answered here (especially because you didn't even specify your terminal in the question).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the font size, but you can use [colorama](https://github.com/tartley/colorama) to make it **bold**, brighter, and colored.